# How to find an audio file's length (in seconds)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio

(Objective C) 
Just using simple AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundID and its counterparts, but I can't find in the documentation if there is already a way to find the length of an audio file.

I know there is AudioServicesGetPropertyInfo, but that seems to return a byte-buffer - do audio files embed their length in themselves and I can just extract it with this?

Or is there perhaps a formula based on bit-rate * fileSize to convert to length-of-time?

mIL3S

www.milkdrinkingcow.com

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to a quick Google search, there is a formula:

```
length-of-time (duration in seconds) = fileSize (in bytes) / bit-rate (bits/secs)*8
```

Is there any particular reason you're using System Sound Services to play a sound?

If you use AVAudioPlayer to handle your sounds you could do something like:

```
AVAudioPlayer * sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil];
sound.delegate = self;
sound.volume = 1;
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", sound.duration]);
```

Comment: Ya, I suppose I should just use AVAudioPlayer. I guess since I was just playing a few little sounds the AudioServices was okay; now that I need more info from it I should probably switch over. Thanks for the formula though! I though there might be something like that. mIL3S

Answer (score 12):

sample code from answer [How to get the duration of an audio file in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219379/how-to-get-the-duration-of-an-audio-file-in-ios). This is the best answer.

```
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:audioFileURL options:nil];
CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
float audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
```

Comment: This is the best general way to achieve this IMO.

Answer (score 0):

See at:

```
Float64 fileDuration = PrepareFileAU (fileAU, fileFormat, audioFile);
```

see ADC sample at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PlayFile/Introduction/Intro.html

without using AVPlayer...

Comment: But isn't this only for Mac OS X? The question is tagged with iPhone.