# Get playback time of audio m4a file ios

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, m4a

I want to get the m4a audio playback time without player implementation.

I found AVAsset implementation but didn't worked for me.

Comment: Try to get the duration like this

`AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:audioFileURL options:nil];
CMTime duration = audioAsset.duration;
float audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

playbacktime can only be used when using MPMediaPalyback

From AVAsset you can get only the duration of the Asset not the playback time.

below is a refernce link

[How to get the duration of an audio file in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219379/how-to-get-the-duration-of-an-audio-file-in-ios)

You can access the duration property of the audio file but you cannot get the playback time.

Playback time will only be available when you are using a player. :-)