# Playing audio with progress bar in each TableViewcell

Tags: objective-c

There is a UITableView,and I have placed a audio button in my each cell,on tapping of the button there is a progress bar that should start playing..and when I tap on play button it should show stop button and progress should be done in the progress bar.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:             (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:nil];

    }
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:14.0]];

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    UILabel *name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 240, 30)];
    name.text=[audiosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    name.tag=indexPath.row;
    name.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:name];

   playBtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 20, 20)];
    [playBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    playBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    [playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(playBtnClk:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:playBtn];
    stopBtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 20, 20)];
    [stopBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    stopBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    [stopBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(stopAudio) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:stopBtn];    
    progressBar=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 20)];
    progressBar.maximumValue = audioPlayer.duration;
    [progressBar addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:
     UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:progressBar];
    return cell;
}
    -(IBAction)playBtnClk:(id)sender{
    ;

    UIButton *selectedBtn=(UIButton*)sender;
    [progressBar setHidden:NO];
    [stopBtn setHidden:NO];
       NSString *songStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[audiosArray objectAtIndex:selectedBtn.tag]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:[songStr stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];
        NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                   initWithContentsOfURL:url
                   error:&error];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
        if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self playAudio];
    }

        playbackTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

   // progressBar.maximumValue = audioPlayer.duration;
    // Set the valueChanged target
//    [progressBar addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:
//     UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
    -(void)playAudio
{
    playbackTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
    -(void)stopAudio
{
    [playBtn setHidden:NO];
    [playbackTimer invalidate];
    [audioPlayer stop];
}
    -(void)adjustVolume
{
    if (audioPlayer != nil)
    {
        audioPlayer.volume = volumeControl.value;
    }
}
    -(void)updateTime
{
    float minutes = floor(audioPlayer.currentTime/60);
    float seconds = audioPlayer.currentTime - (minutes * 60);
    float duration_minutes = floor(audioPlayer.duration/60);
    float duration_seconds =
    audioPlayer.duration - (duration_minutes * 60);  
    NSString *timeInfoString = [[NSString alloc]
                                initWithFormat:@"%0.0f.%0.0f / %0.0f.%0.0f",
                                minutes, seconds,
                                duration_mi`enter code here`nutes, duration_seconds];    timerLabel.text = timeInfoString; }




 - (void)updateSlider {
    // Update the slider about the music time
    progressBar.value = audioPlayer.currentTime;
}
    - (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    // Fast skip the music when user scroll the UISlider
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioPlayer setCurrentTime:progressBar.value];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hyy2JfuXko) video of how to make a custom `UITableViewCell`. Or if you prefer a step by step tutorial [this one](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/) is good. You can then but you play/stop button as well as a progress bar indicating the time left of your sound.

The technique to calculate the length of your sound can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630176/how-to-find-an-audio-files-length-in-seconds).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not a problem with Custom cell,My problem is when I tap on play button ,I need to add progress bar and stop button in same cell..

Comment: Add a UIProgressBar to the cell and hide it if the sound is not currently playing. When the user taps the play button ->> unhide the progress bar and change the button image to the stop button image.

Comment: Hi Filip can you please do some thing

Comment: I have given you the essential idea of how to solve this problem. I don't have a mind to write your code for you. Sorry.

Comment: when i am taps on play button i am adding stopbutton and slider,when i am scrolling tableview it was disappearing.

Comment: When you are scrolling the table -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method will be called and change the cell content! You need to put all cell layout changes in that method.

Comment: Filip and  user1969021 sir i play audio in each cell but slider is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

use this code to play audio in each cell.
But Slider not working properly.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *duration;

    newTableViewCell *cell;
    NSMutableArray *arr_music;
    NSInteger tag;
    NSString *str_music;
    NSTimer *updateTimer;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) YMCAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;


@property BOOL isPaused;
@property BOOL scrubbing;

@property NSTimer *timer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
```

ViewController.m

```
 - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
    {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %ld %ld",(long)indexPath.row,(long)indexPath.section];
        cell = (newTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell=nil;
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"newTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];


        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[newTableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (newTableViewCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (tag==indexPath.row)
    {
        [cell.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_pause.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if (!self.scrubbing)
        {
            NSTimeInterval time     = 0;
            NSTimeInterval maxTime  = 0;
            time    = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
            maxTime = [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration];
            cell.currentTimeSlider.value = (float)(time/maxTime);
            //cell.currentTimeSlider.value = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
        }
        cell.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                 [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];
        cell.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                              [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration] - [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];
        if (![self.audioPlayer isPlaying])
        {
            [cell.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_play.png"]
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
            self.isPaused = FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioplayer_play.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    cell.playButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAudioPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.currentTimeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(userIsScrubbing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [cell.currentTimeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(setCurrentTime:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void)setupAudioPlayer:(NSString*)fileName
{
    NSString *fileExtension = @"mp3";
    [self.audioPlayer initPlayer:fileName fileExtension:fileExtension];
    cell.currentTimeSlider.maximumValue = [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.currentTimeSlider);
    NSLog(@"%f",cell.currentTimeSlider.maximumValue);
    cell.timeElapsed.text = @"0:00";
    cell.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration]]];
    duration=cell.duration.text;
}

- (IBAction)userIsScrubbing:(id)sender
{
    self.scrubbing = TRUE;
}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [_tableview reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)playAudioPressed:(id)playButton
{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)playButton;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)btn.tag);
    if (tag==btn.tag)
    {
        tag=-1;
        [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        [_tableview reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        tag=btn.tag;
        NSTimeInterval time     = 0;
        NSTimeInterval maxTime  = 0;
        time    = [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime];
        maxTime = [self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration];
        duration= (float)(time/maxTime);

        NSLog(@"%f",cell.currentTimeSlider.value);
        NSLog(@"%f",duration);

        if ((cell.currentTimeSlider.value==duration))
        {
            str_music=[arr_music objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
            [self setupAudioPlayer:str_music];

            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
            [self.audioPlayer playAudio];
        }
        else if([[arr_music objectAtIndex:btn.tag]isEqualToString:str_music])
        {
            cell.timeElapsed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                     [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];
            cell.duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                  [self.audioPlayer timeFormat:[self.audioPlayer getAudioDuration] - [self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]]];

            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
            [self.audioPlayer playAudio];
        }
        else
        {
            str_music=[arr_music objectAtIndex:tag];
            [self setupAudioPlayer:str_music];
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
            [self.audioPlayer playAudio];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)setCurrentTime:(id)scrubber
{

    NSLog(@"%f",cell.currentTimeSlider.value);
    NSLog(@"%f",[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]);
   // [self.audioPlayer setCurrentAudioTime:cell.currentTimeSlider.value];
    NSLog(@"%f",[self.audioPlayer getCurrentAudioTime]);
    self.scrubbing = FALSE;
}
```